# How to make slide-out control using fltk

Tags: c++, user-interface, fltk

This is the layout

[image: layout]

When user hover to blue/green group, it will expand itself by using resize, and if mouse leaving the group it will resize back to default size, I've tried using:

1. callback, immediately notice there's no event that handle enter/leave mouse.
2. overriding FL_GROUP and handle "handle(int e) manually, found out that FL_ENTER only got called once, FL_LEAVE only got called after mouse leave the window, instead of leaving the group.

Anymore idea?

Comment: Have a look at the menu code.  That is basically a slide out control: only it appears vertically.  The behaviour is similar to what you want: when you're outside the menu, it closes up.

Comment: @cup found out the problem for resizing when enter and leave, it seems I made a mistake and pass 1 to all event. Having new problem though it seems like a bug, FL_LEAVE using old width/height(before resized) so it got called before leaving new widget size. Probably trying to fix it before trying to implement it based on FL_MENU.

Comment: Menus can appear to the side too.